# Memoization in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, caching, dynamic-programming, memoization

My code in matlab is running very slow and one of the main reasons is that i do not exploit properties of the problem to make things faster. When i try to do so, i end up making the code heavier and slow the execution time even more. The problem is as follows.

Imagine a structure array containing a number of entries, say 100, i.e., `my_structure(1).sequence` to `my_structure(100).sequence`. Each of these entries contains a sequence of zeros and ones of potentially different lengths,i.e, `my_structure(1).sequence=[0 0 1 0]`, `my_structure(2).sequence=[0 1 1 0 0 0 1]` etc. Each of this is used as an input in let's say a black box operation but  `my_structure(2).sequence', for example, will make use of all the previous structures (`my_structure(1).sequence'). In my problem, i try different combinations of these structural arrays and this is what is going on essentially within my loops:

```
#iteration 1
my_structure(1).sequence=[0 0 0 0]
my_structure(2).sequence=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
...
my_structure(100).sequence=[0 0 0 0 1]

#iteration 2
my_structure(1).sequence=[0 0 0 0]
my_structure(2).sequence=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
...
my_structure(100).sequence=[0 0 0 1 0]
```

But, for the second iteration i am recalculating everything from 1-100 while i could just reuse the knowledge from previous iterations and calculate only the updated version of `my_structure(100).sequence`. Is there an easy and effective way to achieve this kind of behaviour in matlab? I have used containers to store the input as key and the outcome as a value. But having a huge binary string as a key was not that effective.

Let me know if you need any clarifications.

Comment: For each struct array element, every field is a pointer, meaning the data is not organized in contiguous memory. This can make access slow. You might rethink how your data is organized and use a logical matrix instead of a structure, or a double matrix with NaNs for padding.

Comment: each row let's say has a different size..how can you do that then?

Comment: If the maximum length of your sequences is small enough, you can create a `100 x Max` logical array and a vector of corresponding valid lengths.

Comment: will this solve the issue of not recalculating utilities at each iteration though? No.. I dont see how it will improve the speed

Answer (score 1):

If you necessarily don't need to use a structure you could use cells instead allowing you to speed up things. Note the curly braces:

```
my_structure{1} = [0 0 0 0]
my_structure{2} = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
...
my_structure{100} = [0 0 0 0 1]
```

Comment: this is what i had before and then tried the structure. I am not sure whether this is faster or not.  However, none of the approaches make use of the fact that structures or cells share a lot of common things at each iteration.